# Angular2: Route redirect with AuthGuard

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

I've an Angular2 app that should block route to a certain page if user is not logged in. This is my app.routes file

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: '**', component: LoginComponent },
];
```

and my AuthGuard file

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
response: ResponseInterface;

constructor(private router: Router, private localStorage: LocalStorageService,
 private services: MyService) { }
canActivate() {

let token = String(this.localStorage.get('token'));
if (token != null) {
  this.services.keepAlive(token).subscribe(
    response => this.response = response,
    error => alert(error),
    () => {
      if (this.response.status == 'OK') {
        console.log("response OK");
        return true;
      } else {
        console.log("response KO");
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
      }
    }
  )

} else {
  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  return false;
}
```

now, if i try to navigate to http://localhost:4200/#/home path and I already have a token stored into localStorage, nothing happen: home page is not showed and path on navigation bar become http://localhost:4200/#/.
What's wrong?

Comment: So do you see the "response OK" in the log?

Comment: yes, response is OK

Comment: No what I mean is you have a `console.log("response OK");` in your code. Do you see it in the console log?

Comment: i receive both response OK, and "response OK" is showed into log, so that portion of code is reached

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`canActive` method should return either `Observable<boolean>`, `Promise<boolean>` or `boolean`.

You're subscribing to the `this.services.keepAlive` Observable, and returning `boolean` value to the  subscribe callback instead of returning it to the `canActivate` method. Change your code as following:

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    let token = String(this.localStorage.get('token'));
    if (token != null) {
        return this.services.keepAlive(token)
            .map(response => {
                if (response.status == 'OK') {
                    console.log("response OK");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    console.log("response KO");
                    this.router.navigate(['login']);
                    return false;
                }
            });
    } else {
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

This way, the Observable of a boolean type ( `Observable<boolean>` ) will be returned to the `canActive` method, and route resolving should work as expected.

Comment: It is subscribing to observable and returning boolean to the subscribe callback, instead of returning it to the canActive method.

Comment: i get this error on canActivate() signature:

'No best common type exists among return expressions.'

Comment: Define the return types for the canActive method as following: canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean { ... }. I will update the answer as well.